# React native packager fails on node 6.5

Tags: react-native

This was working previously. But since I upgraded from node 4.6 to 6.5, When I do an `npm start`, I end up with below error

```
Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: String.prototype.es6
  Paths: ...../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js collides with ...../app/MallJell/nd/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Error: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: String.prototype.es6
  Paths: ....../react-native/packager/react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js collides with ..../react-packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/String.prototype.es6.js

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (..../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:155:13)
    at module.getName.then.name (.....node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/HasteMap.js:115:31)
```

Comment: Have you tried to update your node_modules after updating node...? npm install

Comment: Did you upgrade your React-Native or did you copy some files from somewhere to your React-Native directory recently? Consider the message `Duplicate module name: String.prototypr.es6`

Comment: @AbdulAhad: I removed my node_modules completely and then ran `npm install` followed by `npm start`

Comment: @efkan: All code is part of a git repository. Just doing a fresh checkout and then the steps above causes the error. I am only upgrading `node` and `npm`. My RN is already at 0.32

Comment: Thanks for the responses, When I tried this fresh (removing node_modules) and then npm cache clean just now, I see its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm just putting the answer that worked for you here so others can see it.**

Remove the node_modules folder

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then clean the npm cache and install the modules back

```
npm cache clean && npm install
```

Then run the packager again

```
npm start
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. But the above solution doesn't work for me. Any help?

Comment: Do you have the same error after running the commands above or does the error change ?

Comment: I have the same error. The above steps make no difference

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem by modifing the code of “packag.json”.And then reinstall nodemodules.

Before:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
```

After

```
"scripts": {
       "start": "react-native start"
},
```